# show in ListView

Tags: android-studio

I am new.
I can't understand the logic of how to add to the list. Please help
in this code finally show in listview : "c"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
list = new ArrayList<>();

testt = new Test();
testt.a = "aa";
testt = new Test();
list.add(testt);
testt.a = "cc";

adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

```
public class Test  {
    String a;
    public  Test(){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

i use **list.add(testt);** after **testt=new Test();**

Why listview is not null?

i use **list.add(testt);** after **testt=new Test();**

Why listview is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different objects of `Test` to add them in a list

```
Test test1 = Test();
test1.a = "A";
    
Test test2 = Test();
test2.a = "B";
    
list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(test1);
list.add(test2);
```